# SQL query how to print out manager name?

Tags: sql

I need to create a query to display employee name and number along with their super's name and super number. Listing should also include employees who don't have any supervisor.

```
Select  e.ename,e.empno,super.ename,super from emp e;
```

I don't know how to print out the manager/supervisor name, i just need that.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to itself using an *outer* join:

```
select e.ename, e.empno, super.ename, super.empno
from emp e
left join emp super on super.empno = e.super_empno
```

The `left join` will still return rows from `emp` that do *not* have a super defined.

#### EDIT

Due to OP's comment, here's how to do it *without* a join (using a nasty correlated sub-query):

```
select
    ename,
    empno,
    (select super.ename from emp where empno = e.super_empno) as super_name,
    super_empno
from emp e;
```

Comment: i cnt use left join
i can only use like where clause.
do u know how to do it which the where clause which prints out the manager name?